# How to create an incremental Record ID for a table with a stored procedure?

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake. I have a Javascript stored procedure that takes a table and appends some data returned by an API call.

I want to automate it as much as possible, so I want to provide the option for the user to pass an input table ***with no native record ID***.
The procedure then creates a temporary record ID column to perform the matching. The numbers must go from 0 to count(*) - 1 to be in line with the API IDs.

I **cannot** use a snowflake sequence. They're extremely unreliable for tables with over a 1000 records since they can skip/duplicate numbers.

```
for(let i = 0; i < inputSize; i++){
        var cmd_addRowNum = `INSERT INTO ${TBL_OUT}(temp_primary_key) 
                            VALUES (${i})`;
        var stmt_addRowNum = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: cmd_addRowNum} );
        var results_addRowNum = stmt_addRowNum.execute();
}
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work since it only affects the value of the first row.
I need to insert on row 1 in the first iteration, then insert on row 2 for the 2nd and so on.

Comment: For subsequent runs of your SP, you can run a select to get the max on your PK column and start your i counter at max + 1. You should add thousands of rows to your values clause for each insertion. The exact number will depend on how wide your rows are. SQL statements have a 1mb limit. You definitely do not want to insert data one row per statement as in the loop.

Comment: I restructured to create a new table with just 1 recid column and insert the current value of I in each iteration.

Then in another statement outside of the loop, I create a table by combining the input table to the RECID that I created in the previous step.

I'm not understanding your final comment though, the statements are being overwritten with each iteration so why would they be greater than 1 MB? They're just 1 insert statement per iteration

Comment: And how would I go about inserting multiple rows per iteration without manually having to write all of the INSERTS? I think my procedure is working but of course it's slow as bricks because it has to execute the inserts one by one

Comment: You can have a javascript loop build the values clause. The issue with 1mb is when you'd insert multiple rows in one statement adding them to the values clause. You could add a number of rows at once, but eventually they'd bump into the 1mb limit. I'll work on a sample later this evening.